# AsyncHttpClient creates how much threads?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, completable-future, asynchttpclient

I use async http client in my code to asynchronously handle GET responses
I can run simultaneously 100 requests in the same time.

I use just on instance of httpClient in container

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
open fun httpClient() = Dsl.asyncHttpClient()
```

Code looks like

```
fun method(): CompletableFuture<String> {
    return httpClient.prepareGet("someUrl").execute()
        .toCompletableFuture()
        .thenApply(::getResponseBody)
}
```

It works fine functionally. In my testing I use mock endpoint with the same url address. But my expectation was that all the requests are handled in several threads, but in profiler I can see that 16 threads are created for AsyncHttpClient, and they aren't destroyed, even if there are no requests to send.

[image: profiler screenshoot]

My expectation was that

- it will be less threads for async client
- threads will be destroyed after some configured timeout
- is there some option to control how much threads can be created by asyncHttpClient?

Am I missing something in my expectations?

**UPDATE 1**
I saw instruction on https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/wiki/Connection-pooling
I found no info on thread pool

**UPDATE 2**
I also created method to do the same, but with handler and additional executor pool

Utility method look like

```
fun <Value, Result> CompletableFuture<Value>.handleResultAsync(executor: Executor, initResultHandler: ResultHandler<Value, Result>.() -> Unit): CompletableFuture<Result> {
    val rh = ResultHandler<Value, Result>()
    rh.initResultHandler()

    val handler = BiFunction { value: Value?, exception: Throwable? ->
        if (exception == null) rh.success?.invoke(value) else rh.fail?.invoke(exception)
    }

    return handleAsync(handler, executor)
}
```

The updated method look like

```
fun method(): CompletableFuture<String> {
    return httpClient.prepareGet("someUrl").execute()
        .toCompletableFuture()
        .handleResultAsync(executor) {
            success = {response ->
                logger.info("ok")
                getResponseBody(response!!)
            }
            fail = { ex ->
                logger.error("Failed to execute request", ex)
                throw ex
            }
    }
}
```

Then I can see that result of GET method is executed in the threads provided by thread pool (previously result was executed in "AsyncHttpClient-3-x"), but additional thread for AsyncHttpClient are still created and not destroyed.

Comment: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/wiki/Connection-pooling describes how to set up the connection pools and thread pools

Comment: I saw the page, but there is nothing about tread pools?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431414/does-asynchttpclient-knows-how-many-threads-to-allocate-for-all-the-http-request ?

Comment: Yes, but still can't understand how it is connected with number of threads. So in my case I have only requests to one host. So in the link provided it is written that should be only one thread, which can handle all the requests. Or all the threads are initialised by default and can be used by AsyncClient to perform it internal job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AHC has two types of threads:

1. For I/O operation. 
   On your screen, it's AsyncHttpClient-x-x
   threads. AHC creates **2*core_number** of those.
2. For timeouts.
   On your screen, it's AsyncHttpClient-timer-1-1 thread. Should be
   only **one**.

Source: issue on GitHub: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/issues/1658

Comment: Thanks a lot. This completely describes the profiler threads picture, as I have 8 Cores on the machine, on which the code was executed